# Variable TTL inside a LAN

Tags: networking, ping, ttl

I recently discovered that ping my local router, returns different TTL values​​.
The ping 3 switch must pass through before reaching the router, there may be the problem?

192.168.1.99 is the IP of my router , a Cisco WRT120N

Thank you!

> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=190
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo=29ms TTL=3
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=117
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=131
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=66
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=66
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=66
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=111
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=240
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=66
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=66
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=66
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=51
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=190
>
> Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=66

Traceroute

```
G:\Documents and Settings\Administrador>tracert 192.168.1.99
```

Traza a la dirección maxi2011 [192.168.1.99]
sobre un máximo de 30 saltos:

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  maxi2011 [192.168.1.99]

Traza completa.

G:\Documents and Settings\Administrador>ping 192.168.1.99

Haciendo ping a 192.168.1.99 con 32 bytes de datos:

Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=190
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=190
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=117
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.99: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=117

Estadísticas de ping para 192.168.1.99:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0
    (0% perdidos),
Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
    Mínimo = 0ms, Máximo = 0ms, Media = 0ms

G:\Documents and Settings\Administrador>

Comment: [Several](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/224662-why-ttl-unstable.html) people have observed [this](http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT120-TTL-prblem/td-p/332193) behavior with the WRT120N. It doesn't appear to be hurting anything.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchwartz , I had not notice these posts!

Answer (score 1):

It is something wrong in your network. A layer 2 switch should not decrease TTL. Only routers decrease TTL by 1 when ICMP packet is routed. And of course target machine. But in your case it should have the same value every time.

Try a mtr or traceroute command.

Comment: Strangely, there are no jumps in the traceroute